# If page has posts in certain category - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I have a client built site that I am adding some functionality too - I don't usually develop using Wordpress. They have built pages using Visual Composer to display posts from varying categories

If the post is within a certain category 'Deals' I want to do stuff … non-working code (in functions.php) below:

```
function deals () {
    if ( in_category('Deals') ) {
        echo '<style>.entry-thumb{display: none !important;}</style>';
    }
}
```

Calling function from within child theme page template.

Any help would be great 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check if current post is in category by using

`if( has_category('Deals') ) {
  // do stuff here
}`

If `$post` global variable is set `has_category('Deals')` will be ok. Otherwise you will need to pass post ID as second parameter. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_category/

P.S. If you are calling it in a loop it looks like you are trying to echo the same inline css multiple times. This will hide all `.entry-thumb`s regardless of the category. So it may be better to add a class to your `deal` posts and then use something like `.deal .entry-thumb{ display: none; }` in your style.css.

Answer (score 0):

You should try is_category() function like this:

```
function deals () {
  if ( is_category('Deals') ) {
   echo '<style>.entry-thumb{display: none !important;}</style>';
  }
}
```